# How does the Draconic Bloodline sorcerer's Elemental Affinity feature interact with the Scorching Ray spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, damage, sorcerer

The [Draconic Bloodline sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#DraconicBloodline)'s **Elemental Affinity** feature description (PHB, page 102) says:

> ...when you cast a spell that deals damage of the type associated with your draconic ancestry, you can add your Charisma modifier to one damage roll of that spell.

The [**Scorching Ray**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scorching-ray) spell description (PHB, page 273) says:

> You create three rays of fire and can hurl them at targets within range. You can hurl them at one target or several.
>
> *Make a ranged spell attack for each ray.* On a hit, the target takes 2d6 fire damage.

Because I make an individual ranged spell attack for each ray of fire, and I have fire elemental affinity, can I add my Charisma modifier to each of the rays? Would it just impact one of the rays, because it's through one spell cast?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As this question has previously been asked, I've closed it as a duplicate of the previous question. That's not a criticism of you or the question - it helps others find the previous question! Hope you stick around :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It would only apply to one ray

As you stated, the rules (post errata) state when and how you can use that feature (PHB, p. 102, bold added):

> ...**when you cast a spell** that deals damage of the type associated with your draconic ancestry, you can add you Charisma modifier to **one damage roll** of that spell.

The feature does not say that you can use this feature each time you make an attack, or each time you roll damage, but each time you cast a spell: and on one damage roll of that spell.

The spell *Scorching Ray* involves several attacks and (provided more than one hits) several damage rolls, but it's only one spell. You may use your *elemental affinity* feature on only one of those rolls.

Note that for a spell that has only one damage roll but affects multiple targets (like *Fireball*), the increase in damage from *elemental affinity* would apply to every target of the spell, because the spell has only one damage roll that applies to all the affected targets. But for a spell like Scorching Ray, you'll only be able to increase the damage once, because each ray has a separate damage roll.